# Building a Spring-boot project without eclipse gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm fairly new to gradle and writing a project that I have working in eclipse and was posed with the challenge to write it without eclipse using gradle.  I'm finding that even once I add the spring framework configurations to my build file it still can not see what I am importing.  I am also using maven so I think it my understanding of gradle changing from a maven project and with SQL. Any thoughts?

Here is my **build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.9.RELEASE"
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

// spring dependency management plugin configuration
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    // select versions based on this BOM
    mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.1.RELEASE'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
  compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spring boot dependencies.

like:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

See the Spring documentation:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't see imports like it doesn't see spring.

Comment: posted the changes